# Need to change the ID for different topics

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having one h1 section header and their corresponding para's (para,list) and lot of h2 section header and their corresponding para's (para,list). I want to change the each h1 and h2 as topic with different ID's

XML Input as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ImportArticle>
    <Segments>
        <Segment>
            <Body>
                <h1>Essay on Education</h1>
                <h2>Importance of Education Essay</h2>
                <p>Following are different types of essay topics</p>
                <h2>Essay on Music</h2>
                <p>Education is the systematic process of improving learning</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                        <b>Find understandable essay.</b> Education essay is the most important</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>
                        <b>Education is the act.</b> It helps us to easily understand and deal with any problem.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p>It improves our knowledge, skill, confidence level and personality.</p>
            </Body>
        </Segment>
    </Segments>
</ImportArticle>
```

XSL I Used as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    doctype-public="urn:pubid:com.doctype.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic"
    doctype-system="topic.dtd"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="ImportArticle">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="dita.xsl"</xsl:processing-instruction>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Segments">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Segment">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h1">
<topic id="topic_1">
    <title>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </title>
</topic>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <topic id="topic_2">
      <title>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </title>
    </topic>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <b>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </b>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I'm getting as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="DITA.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.doctypes.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
<title>Essay on Education</title>
</topic>
<topic id="topic_2">
<title>Importance of Education Essay</title>
</topic>
<p>Following are different types of essay topics</p>
<topic id="topic_2">
<title>Essay on Music</title>
</topic>
<p>Education is the systematic process of improving learning</p>
<ul>
<li><p><b>Find understandable essay.</b> Education essay is the most important</p></li>
<li><p><b>Education is the act.</b> It helps us to easily understand and deal with any problem.</p></li>
</ul>
<p>It improves our knowledge, skill, confidence level and personality.</p>
```

But I'm expecting output as "h1" topic needs to close after all the "h2" closes and each "h2" needs come in different id and para and list are come as per the input places:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="DITA.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.doctypes.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
<title>Essay on Education</title>
<topic id="topic_2">
<title>Importance of Education Essay</title>
<p>Following are different types of essay topics</p>
</topic>
<topic id="topic_3">
<title>Essay on Music</title>
<p>Education is the systematic process of improving learning</p>
<ul>
<li><p><b>Find understandable essay.</b> Education essay is the most important</p></li>
<li><p><b>Education is the act.</b> It helps us to easily understand and deal with any problem.</p></li>
</ul>
<p>It improves our knowledge, skill, confidence level and personality.</p>
</topic>
</topic>
```

Please give me suggestion on this and thanks in advance

Comment: Why not generate automatically an id with the function generate-id() like  <topic id="{generate-id()}">...</topic>

Comment: Please show a **complete** XML input, including the root element.

Comment: I Have edited @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use XSLT 2.0 as indicated you can use `for-each-group starting-with="h1"`:

```
<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    doctype-public="urn:pubid:com.doctype.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic"
    doctype-system="topic.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="dita.xsl"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Body"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Body">        
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
                <topic>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                    </title>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
                        <topic>
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <title>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                            </title>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."
/>                        </topic>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </topic>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSQ/2.

Comment: Title's are missing while i'm using this tag @Martin. Please help on this

Comment: That template name "body" creating validation error. is there is any possible to use some other template name @Martin

Comment: Please edit your input sample and show us the name of the parent element of all those elements, then we can adapt the code to copy that parent element instead of making one up. What is the target format, is that not HTML?

Comment: I have edited the code again, obviously if you have a `Body` instead of `body` the adaption to `match="Body"` should be obvious, and if you don't want the `Body` element in the output then the `xsl:copy` needs to be removed.

Comment: Its working fine @martin. But unwanted namespace coming in <p> tag (<p xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">) even i used  exclude-result-prefixes="#all". Please give me suggestion

Comment: Post a new question if you can't fix that on your own, the current question does not have any `p` element with those namespace declarations and does not create any.